# Rails: Design pattern to modify params based on users type before passing on to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

There are mulitple controller actions that receive startDate as a parameter and pass it on to relevant models to fetch the data. Based on a user property, there are validation rules that has to be applied on this parameter. Validation wouldn't just fail, but instead assigns a default value specific to that user property.

The modification required on startDate is common across all the actions and should be applied in all the cases. So, i assume this logic shouldn't be repeated at each model. Instead, controller's before_action filter, something like filtered_params sounds the right place to do it.

```
before_action :filtered_params

def filtered_params
   params.require(:query).permit(:start_date)
   user = User.instance
   if(user.type == 'student') {} # startDate should be Greater than or equal to 12-03-2018. modify params.startDate with the logic
   elsif(user.type == 'professor') {} // startDate should be Greater than equal to 01-01-2018
   else {} // do nothing
   end
end
```

The above approach works, but i do not want to get stuck in if else loop. Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean "`else` loop"? Why would you *modify* `startDate` instead of just validate it? Why are you doing it here instead of in normal validation logic?

Comment: validating the input is one part of it. i'll have to assign it a default value if the validation fails based on the user type. These checks are to applied for multiple actions and not just one.

Comment: Then this should be done in a validation method or callback. The method can live in a utility class so the business logic is isolated. That said, IMO this is a suspicious requirement: if a user enters an incorrect date they should correct it, not get a default value that may not reflect reality.

Comment: let me elaborate on that.The backend services we make a call to has some data attributed on all the dates. But, the requirement is in a way that when the user type got changed from one to another, we should show the relevant info only from the date the type has changed. So, if a student has become a professor on 15th May and he selects last 3 months as the date range, controller should modify the start date to 15th May because the data attributed to the user before 15th May is invalid and shouldn't be shown. We can clear DB but it is used by other systems.

Comment: IMO the controller should *not* do that. Controllers are a thin line between the web and the business logic. Business logic should be implemented in models and/or utilities and/or concerns. Transforming data is not the job of a controller.

Comment: @DaveNewton - My Hero! POROs for business logic == unicorns and lemon drops.

Comment: I cannot agree more. How well can a utility be written that doesn't the if-else loops. Because, there can be reqs where similiar validations can be placed on other params or the number of user types might keep increasing. Is there a polymorphis(for the lack of better word) way of seperating the concerns according to type and keep the code clean

Comment: @Sanjay I don't know why you keep saying "loop". There's no loop. Yes, they're called "concerns". Or it can just be a utility class used where needed.

Comment: @Sanjay - Did you take a look at my answer? PORO service with no `if` logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could do something like:

```
before_action :filtered_params

def filtered_params
  @filtered_params ||= get_filtered_params
end

def get_filtered_params
  # not sure about this user assignment, but let's go with it...
  user = User.instance
  begin
    "ParamsFilter::#{user.type.camelize}Service".constantize.call params
  rescue NameError => e
    # I'm guessing at the default behavior here. You would need to 
    # modify to meet your requirements.
    return params.require(:query).permit(:start_date)
  end
end
```

Then you would need something like:

```
app
 |- services
 |   |- params_filter
 |   |   |- service_base.rb
 |   |   |- student_service.rb
 |   |   |- professor_service.rb
 |   |- service_base.rb
```

And a service might look something like

```
class ParamsFilter::StudentService < ParamsFilter::ServiceBase

  MIN_START_DATE = '12-03-2018'

  #======================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #======================================================================

    def call
      # In this case, given how ServiceBase is defined, the params will 
      # be received as `args`, so you'll need to work with the `args` 
      # variable, which will contain `params`.

      # You could do stuff unique to `student`:
      student_stuff

      # and then do some common stuff by calling `super`.
      super

    end

  private

    def student_stuff
    end

end
```

Where `ParamsFilter::ServiceBase` might look something like:

```
class ParamsFilter::ServiceBase < ServiceBase

  #======================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #======================================================================

    def call
      args[:start_date] = self.class::MIN_START_DATE unless start_date_okay?
    end

  private 

    def start_date_okay?
      args[:start_date] >= self.class::MIN_START_DATE
    end

end
```

Where `service_base.rb` might look something like:

```
class ServiceBase

  attr_accessor *%w(
    args
  ).freeze

  class << self

    def call(args=nil)
      new(args).call
    end

  end # Class Methods

  #======================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #======================================================================

  def initialize(args)
    @args = args
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @jvillian, i was looking for something exactly like this. clean code, a design pattern, no duplication.

Comment: Glad it's helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As Dave notes, this is odd behavior. However, if you must alter the start_date, consider using a before_validation callback. It's much safer/cleaner NOT to alter the incoming params, but do it at the model level.

```
class User

MINIMUM_STUDENT_START_DATE = '12-03-2018'
MINIMUM_PROFESSOR_START_DATE = '01-01-2018'

before_validation :set_start_date

def set_start_date
  if type == 'student' && start_date < MINIMUM_STUDENT_START_DATE
    self.start_date = MINIMUM_STUDENT_START_DATE
  elsif type == 'professor' && start_date < MINIMUM_PROFESSOR_START_DATE
    self.start_date = MINIMUM_PROFESSOR_START_DATE
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems like you may want `start_date = ` to be `params[:start_date] = `, no? Otherwise, `start_date` is just a local variable to `set_start_date` and doesn't do anything. Or, perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @jvillian more like `self.start_date =`. No `params` in the model. :)

Comment: true that. it should be params[:start_date] and should be replaced with MIN_STU_START_DATE only if it isn't already

Comment: @Sanjay No. There is no `params` in the model.

Comment: Yup, forgot the `self` thanks @SergioTulentsev

At the point where a before_validation runs, the `start_date` should have already been set. If not, there should probably be another validation to reject and prompt the user to set one. Or I suppose one could set for the user  since that seems to be the sort of thing this client is into...

Comment: Personally I'd put the date logic somewhere else entirely and refer to it in the `User` model since OP says this runs across models. That means it's likely a concern, or a simple utility class. I'd also put the types/dates in a hash, validate the key, and wrap it all up.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about the original question which was in the context of a controller, not a model. And, I missed the `class User` in Isaiah's answer. It is unclear to me from the question whether `start_date` is an attribute of `User`... Personally, I would put this in a simple utility class. (Concerns, ew!)

Comment: @DaveNewton i am sorry, i think we are getting off track, model receives the start Date as one of the parameters. params are definitely controller's thing. i was just replying to another comment on this thread.

Comment: @Sanjay Params are a controller thing. This is not a controller. Nor does this logic belong in a controller.

Comment: I give up @DaveNewton, i know params are controller thing, code block used in my question is from controller, whereas the class User used in this solution is a Model.

Comment: @IsaiahFasoldt, as i mentioned in the question, User Model has nothing to do with it, we use user's type and then pass on the startdate to different models for different actions, like Reports Model to fetch reports, Referral Model, transactions Model etc.. And it doesn't make sense to add these validations at each model level. so, the best thing in my opinion is to, validate and update before the model comes into picture

Comment: @Sanjay You're setting a date on a user. How does the user model have nothing to do with it? Regardless: controllers are not the place to transform data: controllers are a place to take in request data and decide what to do next. Models or business logic services are the place to transform data.

Comment: @Sanjay Correct; this shouldn't be done in the controller, hence there's no `params` in the `User` model shown here.

Comment: @DaveNewton i think it was my mistake to throw User Model into the question. Based on which user is accessing the website (fetched from User singleton), start date should be modified before passed onto any model(Reports, Downloads, Transactions, Referrals etc..) This logic shouldn't be in controller and i agree, i am just looking at the best way to approach this, so that the utility/concern doesn't have if else looping hell.

Comment: @Sanjay There is no loop. I'm not sure what you mean by "singleton" here; if there is a single instance of a `User` following around requests, you've just built a single-user system that two people cannot use at once, which seems bizarre.